# Phpstorm - PhoneGap emulator doesn't start

Tags: android, cordova, phpstorm

I'm trying to run PhoneGap on PhpStorm, howerver the emulation itself does not start.
Here is my configuration:
[image]
When I run it this appears in the console:

```
"D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 8.0.3\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Users\Milen\AppData\Roaming\npm\phonegap.cmd run --emulator android
[phonegap] executing 'cordova run --emulator android'...
[phonegap] completed 'cordova run --emulator android'
```

...but the emulator does not start. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: does it start when you run 'C:\Users\Milen\AppData\Roaming\npm\phonegap.cmd run --emulator android' in your windows cmd console?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't solved it yet :P, then try to add the [Android SDK path]/platform-tools to the PATH environment variable on Windows.